# How to reduce battery power 10v 1.5A to 6v 1.5A

Tags: battery

What's least complex way to reduce power from a 10V 1.5A battery to 6V 1.5A

Thank you!

Comment: I answered my own question. Here it is;

http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75448/how-to-reduce-dc-voltage-using-resistors

Answer (score 1):

If your current requirements are indeed over an ampere, 
use a buck converter, that is, switching DC-DC converter.  (For example, search for `6V 3A buck` on ebay and you will see a lot of such converters for about $2.50 each, delivered.)  A buck converter's efficiency typically is 85 to 95%.  If you use resistors, your efficiency can be no better than 60%, and regulation will be quite poor:  you will get your desired voltage only at some certain current draw, and higher or lower voltages at other draws.

Here's a picture of a typical example.  It is labeled as 12V in, but it actually works with input voltages in the range from 8V to over 20V, ie, maintains close to 6V output for output currents up to 3A and input voltages from 8V to over 20V. 
[image: 6V 3A buck]